# How to Parallelize Ray Tracing Code in Python for Full CPU Utilization

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I've written a simple Python script for ray tracing, which generates an image of a sphere illuminated by multiple light sources. The code uses the Pillow library for image creation and basic Python math functions for calculations. Here's the full code:

```
from PIL import Image
from math import pi, tan
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
aspect_ratio = WIDTH / HEIGHT
sphere_pos = [0, 0, 0]
sphere_radius = 100
sphere_color = (255, 0, 0)
camera_pos = [0, 0, -500]
fov = pi / 3
fov_adjustment = tan(fov / 2)
fova = aspect_ratio * fov_adjustment
light_positions = [[400, 100, -500], [-200, 300, -400]]
light_colors = [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 0)]
def dot_product(v1, v2):
    return sum((a*b) for a, b in zip(v1, v2))
def normalize(v):
    len_v = dot_product(v, v) ** .5
    return [x / len_v for x in v]
img = Image.new('RGB', (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
imgl = img.load()
for y in range(HEIGHT):
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        ray_direction = normalize([(2 * (x + 0.5) / WIDTH - 1) * fova, (1 - 2 * (y + 0.5) / HEIGHT) * fov_adjustment, 1])
        oc = [a - b for a, b in zip(camera_pos, sphere_pos)]
        a = dot_product(ray_direction, ray_direction)
        b = 2.0 * dot_product(oc, ray_direction)
        c = dot_product(oc, oc) - sphere_radius**2
        discriminant = b**2 - 4*a*c
        if discriminant > 0:
            intersection_point = [camera_pos[i] + ray_direction[i] * min((-b + discriminant ** .5) / (2.0 * a), (-b - discriminant ** .5) / (2.0 * a)) for i in range(3)]
            normal = normalize([intersection_point[i] - sphere_pos[i] for i in range(3)])
            color = (0, 0, 0)
            for light_pos, light_col in zip(light_positions, light_colors):
                light_direction = normalize([light_pos[i] - intersection_point[i] for i in range(3)])
                intensity = max(0, dot_product(normal, light_direction))
                color = (color[0] + int(sphere_color[0] * intensity * light_col[0] / 255),color[1] + int(sphere_color[1] * intensity * light_col[1] / 255),color[2] + int(sphere_color[2] * intensity * light_col[2] / 255))
            imgl[x, y] = color
        else:
            imgl[x, y] = (0, 0, 0)
img.show()
```

The current implementation processes each pixel sequentially, which is inefficient given the CPU-intensive nature of ray tracing. My machine has multiple CPU cores, and I'd like to utilize them to speed up the rendering process.

Questions:

Comment: Python is really not a language for such a thing. A good ray-tracing code should be vectorized using SIMD instructions. This is actually pretty hard to do in mainstream native language like C/C++/Rust (so a specific SIMD-aware native language may be used instead). This is impossible to write an efficient code in Python. Tools like Numba/Cython help a lot but they are not enough to write an efficient implementation.

Comment: On top of that, Python parallelism (kind of) sucks : multithreading is limited by the GIL (aka global interpreter lock) and multiprocessing is limited by inter-process-communication. Numba/Cython offer a way to do multithreading without the GIL but with strong limitations (no pure-Python objects and a simple parallel model which is very-limited IMHO).

Comment: You can use multiple process (using the multiprocessing package or joblib for example) to make your code run in parallel but it will be certainly at least two order of magnitude than an optimized code (maybe even 3 order of magnitude so a sequential optimized code can outperform your parallel implementation).